# If Java program compiled to exe or dll for a system without JVM will it certainly be much slower?

Tags: java, dll, jar, jvm, ikvm

If I use tool like IKVM、JSmooth、JarToExe to compiled Jave code to dll or exe that can be executed directly by CPU, will it certainly be much slower then performed on JVM?  But since JVM also need to compile java code to CPU-executable code, then why can't I just tell the Java compiler my CPU architecture and operation system so I can keep the efficiency and run it without JVM??

Comment: Because it's a lot more complicated than that.

Comment: The JVM optimises the code based on how it has been used recently, and it often re-optimises code based on changing usage patterns.